# FaceTime/FaceTime Audio calls to ipad and iphone simultaniously from overseas (15 calls)

Tags: iphone, ipad, facetime

Yesterday I received a call from a strange number: +7 (987) 753-20-26 via FaceTime and FaceTime Audio to my ipad and iphone simultaneously.  I did  not answer because I didn't recognize the number, but each time my face was visible (as though I was on a call).  I had a repairman at the house and as soon as his face was the one that was visible the calls stopped.  There were 15 calls, rapid fire, one after the other often at the same time on each device.  It sort of creeped me out, but then I wondered if our system could have been hacked.  Again, it is an unknown number.

Is there something I need to do to be sure I wasn't hacked?  Could it be a stalker?  Thank you for any suggestions/comments.

Answer (score 1):

> …to my iPad and iPhone simultaneously […] at the same time on each device

You will receive simultaneous calls on all devices with the same Apple ID. This is how FaceTime works and is not due to any action on the part of the caller.

> but each time my face was visible

The background to a FaceTime call that has not been answered will be the camera feed from the front camera on the device. **This is not transmitted anywhere** as the call has not been answered. Any correlation between who is shown on this preliminary screen and the caller is pure coincidence.